How to install torch with CUDA in virtual environment (Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled)
I'm trying to use the joytag model locally. This is requirements.txt:
torch>=2.0.1,<3.0.0
transformers>=4.36.2
torchvision>=0.15.2
einops>=0.7.0
safetensors>=0.4.1
pillow>=9.4.0

They provide a script to run the model. I created a virtual environment to avoid conflicts, I installed the requirements, and when I run the script, I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sync2\IAImages\LoRA\Scripts\TaggingModels\joytag\joytag.py", line 13, in <module>
    model = model.to('cuda')
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Sync2\IAImages\LoRA\Scripts\TaggingModels\joytag\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1174, in to
    return self._apply(convert)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Sync2\IAImages\LoRA\Scripts\TaggingModels\joytag\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 780, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "D:\Sync2\IAImages\LoRA\Scripts\TaggingModels\joytag\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 780, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "D:\Sync2\IAImages\LoRA\Scripts\TaggingModels\joytag\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 780, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "D:\Sync2\IAImages\LoRA\Scripts\TaggingModels\joytag\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 805, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
                    ^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Sync2\IAImages\LoRA\Scripts\TaggingModels\joytag\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1160, in convert
    return t.to(
           ^^^^^
  File "D:\Sync2\IAImages\LoRA\Scripts\TaggingModels\joytag\venv\Lib\site-packages\torch\cuda\__init__.py", line 305, in _lazy_init
    raise AssertionError("Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled")
AssertionError: Torch not compiled with CUDA enabled

I'm not very familiar with Torch and related packages, so it's hard to me to understand what I did wrong.

You have not installed a GPU accelerated PyTorch build. Nothing will work until you install a CUDA enabled build

@talonmies how can I do that? Maybe you can share a tutorial.

Read the installation instructions on the PyTorch homepage. It is that simple

I though that with requirements.txt was engouh, but it isn't. As @talonmies suggested, you should check PyTorch documentation: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
In my case, I ran pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu124 in the virtual environment.
